# PayPal Express Checkout - custom text for deduction amount

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

```
$DeductionAmount = -24.00;
```

I have used the below line for discount

```
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=-'.$DeductionAmount.'
```

In the **PayPal page:**

```
Item total               $81.00
Postage discount        -$24.00
```

---

```
                   Total $57.00
```

I wants to add the discount, but the discount is not regarding shipping/postage discount.

How can I change the '**Postage discount**' to '**Deductions**' / '**Discounts**' (or some custom text)?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use **negative amount** as a line item.

`Example Request:`

```
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
VERSION=80.0
RETURNURL=http://localhost/order_auth_capture/doauthorisation.php
CANCELURL=http://localhost/order_auth_capture/cancel.php
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=8.00 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=8.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD  
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Cofee Mug
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Size: 8.8-oz 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=10.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1

<!-- **Discount parameters** -->
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=Discount
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1=Discount
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=-2.00  
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=1
```

[image]

Old Layout:
[image]

Comment: I have tried this before; Then It showed 'Discount    $-2.00' instead of 'Discount    -$2.00'

Comment: did it work for you now? not sure how u get "$-2.00"

Comment: Let my try one more time.

Comment: Yes, i see that now. in old layout.

Comment: &PAYMENTACTION=Sale&ALLOWNOTE=1&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=57&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=57&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=20&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=4&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=4747M-Feb-2015&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=ORD1000&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=1&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=1&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=Misc+Fee&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1=&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY2=6&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT2=-4.00&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME2=Discount&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER2=&AMT=57&

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer..It shows differently in old,new layouts

Comment: How can I make the change to new?

Comment: its is not possible to force to new layout,(PayPal is transforming all the layout to new layout but its not complete, its evolving as we speak) if you want to raise this as bug, please contact www.paypal.com/mts and submit a ticket.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Ok, You meant we cannot change the format through the API.

Comment: yes, unfortunately not possible to change the format via API.